# async await not working as expected, it must return me future result

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

My code with Future & Then works perfectly. see below:

```
/*main is the entry point of code*/
void main() {

var futureObject = getPostFromServer();
printPost(futureObject);

}
getPostFromServer(){

var duration = Duration(seconds : 5);
var computation = (){
return "You will get it in future" ;
};

var futureObject = Future.delayed(duration, computation);
return futureObject;

}
printPost(var futureObject){
futureObject.then(
(actualString){
print(actualString);
}

);
}
/*
OUTPUT
You will get it in future
*/
```

However, when I am trying the same with async & wait I am not able to get the same output.

```
    Instance of '_Future<dynamic>'
```

Why not I am able to get future value?

```
/*main is the entry point of code*/
void main() {

var futureObject = getPostFromServer();
printPost(futureObject);

}
getPostFromServer() async {

var duration = Duration(seconds : 5);
var computation = (){
return "You will get it in future" ;
};

var futureObject = await Future.delayed(duration, computation);
return futureObject;

}
printPost(var futureObject){
print(futureObject);
}
/*
OUTPUT
start
Instance of '_Future<dynamic>'
end    */
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mark a method with `async`, dart will return you a Future implicitly. So if you want to use the result of this method you have to again await the result.

Below I have awaited the future and then printed it in an async method. So my rule of thumb is always await and do your functionality as you would in a sequential program. If you return a value from an async function you are telling dart that method will take time execute so wrap it in a future and return the results.

In your example getPostFromServer() acts as a mini server in you client side code and printPost() acts as sub client who should wait and then read the results. `async` and `await` are equally important in both server and client side. Only diference would be how we use it. :)

```
void main() {

var futureObject = getPostFromServer();
printPost(futureObject);

}
getPostFromServer() async {

var duration = Duration(seconds : 5);
var computation = (){
return "You will get it in future" ;
};

var futureObject = await Future.delayed(duration, computation);
return futureObject;

}
printPost(var futureObject) async {
 print(await futureObject);
}
```

Same code in dartpad:

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/59610dc768e232ac5a8e724f7fe0eee6